$e^x=kx$ ( where k is an arbitrary constant). Find range of $k$ such that it has two solutions
I know that first solution will be at $k=e$ but can't figure out how to write the range. Also I need help when $k<0$.

The equation $e^x = k x$ has two solution if and only if $k > e$. Draw the graph.

Can you find the value of $k$ such that it has exactly one solution, Chetan? That would be a good start.

Do you know something about differential calculus ? It could help you in this kind of situation

Use desmos to play around with different value of k, then find k when the line is tangent to the graph of $e^x$

Thanks, figured it out.

@Gerry Myerson , hmm yes I found it by putting x=1 which gives me e=k. Therefore the solution is e and it occurs at x=1

Consider three cases here, $k<0$, $k=0$ and $k>0$. Now, for the first case, since $k$ is a negative number, the function $f(x)=e^x-kx$ has a slope:
$$f'(x)=e^x-k$$
Since, $k$ is negative, $e^x-k$ is always positive, so the function is always increasing, there is no change of concavity and the function essentially intersects the $X$-axis only once, resulting in one solution always, so $k$ can never be less than $0$, it needs to be a positive number.
While we have $k=0$, the function $f(x)=e^x$ never intersects the $X$ axis, so is it not necessary to have any further discussions here.
For the third and final case, the equation of slope is $f'(x)=e^x-k$ and there is a change of concavity at the critical point which we find just by setting $f'(x)=0$, which leads to:
$$
e^x=k\Rightarrow x=\ln k
$$
Therefore, the function changes its concavity at $x=\ln k$. Therefore, the coordinate of the point is $$(\ln k, k(1-\ln k))$$ Now, why do we need to study the behavior of critical point? It's because, for a function that's decreasing before the critical point and increasing after the critical point, must have the critical point [local minima] below the X-axis to have two intersection points on the X-axis. On the other hand, the function that's increasing before the critical point and decreasing after the critical point, must have the critical point [local maxima] above the X-axis to have two intersection points on the X-axis.
Ours this function $f(x)$ has a local maxima as its critical point, since $f''(x)=e^x$ is always positive. Therefore, to have our critical point below the $X$-axis, it is necessary to have $k(1-\ln k)$ less than $0$, which means:
$$k(1-\ln k)<0$$
$$\ln k>1\Rightarrow k>e$$
Therefore, the range of value of $k$ is $(e,\infty)$. At these values, the critical point lies below the $X$-axis, the $X$-axis is interesected twice and two solutions are found.

It really helped me, thanks!
